# Inscribed spheres in irregular tetrahedra

Tags: solid-geometry

Let $ABCD$ be an irregular tetrahedron, and let $K$ be the center of its inscribed sphere. Let $M$ be the center of the inscribed sphere of $KBCD$. Are $A$, $M$, $K$ necessarily collinear? I have trouble finding a simple counterexample.

(<s>Having a counterexample would settle the generalization of [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/857273/fin) to complex values</s> *Edit: I found another way around that*).

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Counterexample.

Irregular tetrahedron $ABCD$ with vertices

\begin{align} 
A&=(0,0,1)
,\quad
B=(1,0,0)
,\quad
C=(0,1,0)
,\quad
D=(2,0,0)
\end{align}

has inscribed sphere with 
center $K$ and radius 
\begin{align}
r&=\tfrac1{22}\,(5-\sqrt3)\approx 0.1485
,
\end{align}

tetrahedron $KBCD$
has inscribed sphere 
with center $M$ and radius 
\begin{align}
r_m&=\tfrac1k\,(5-\sqrt3)\approx 0.0657
,\\
k&={22+5\,\sqrt{30}-3\,\sqrt{10}+5\sqrt2-\sqrt6+2\,\sqrt{57-29\,\sqrt3}}
.
\end{align}

Coordinates of the centers are

\begin{align}
K&=\tfrac1{22}(9+7\,\sqrt3, 5-\sqrt3, 5-\sqrt3)
\\
&\approx(0.960,0.149,0.149)
,\\
M_x&=
\tfrac1k\,\left(9+7\,\sqrt3+5\,\sqrt{30}-3\,\sqrt{10}+4\,\sqrt{57-29\,\sqrt3}\right)
,\\
M_y&=
\tfrac1k\,(5-\sqrt3+5\,\sqrt2-\sqrt6)
,\\
M_z&=\tfrac1k\,(5-\sqrt3)
,\\
M&\approx(0.994,0.159,0.0657)
,
\end{align}

\begin{align}
\angle MAK\approx 1.65^\circ
,\\
\angle AKM\approx 154^\circ
,\\
\angle KMA\approx 24.35^\circ
.
\end{align}